# Why does ADB sideload always stop at 47%?

Tags: lineageos, side-loading

When I sideload stuff (like Google Apps) or LineageOS through LineageOS Recovery, it always stops at 47% with the `adb sideload` command. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/af12lu/adb_sideload_instalation_failed_at_47/edvwaex/)

> If I remember correctly (from a discussion long ago), Google's ROMs are transferred about 2.2 times across the sideload. To make the progress bar add up to 100%, they said "2.2 times the file size equals 100%". Our ZIPs are transferred just once, so the final progress is at about 47% with a success. The xfer seems to show the transferred data compared to the file size. Ours clocks in at x1.00 or x1.01, while Google's is about x2.something.